# Calendário Color Sharepoint "Javascript" "Jquery"

Tags: javascript, jquery, navegador-de-internet, sharepoint

Tenho este código abaixo para um calendário no sharepoint 2013
Que quando usuário escolher carro prata no calendário campo ficar na cor prata e quando preto ficar na cor preta.

Ele funciona somente no browser IE, no FireFox e Chrome não funciona, alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

```
    <script src="/sites/SiteAssets/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
<style>

.black{
    background-color: #383838;
}

.silver{
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
}
</style><script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $('.ms-acal-item').each(function(){
            $(':contains("Preto")',this).addClass('black');
            $(':contains("Prata")',this).addClass('silver');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: por via das duvidas tenta alterar de `$(':contains("Preto")',this).addClass('black');` para `$(":contains('Preto')",this).addClass('black');` -> mudar as aspas simples do selector para aspas duplas

Answer (score 0):

Tiago, é bem simples o que você ta querendo fazer, pelo que entendi é só alternar entre classes CSS correto? Segue abaixo um código que faz exatamente a mesma coisa e creio que não ocasionará em problemas de compatibilidade, basta tu referenciar o click dos "carros" assim como esta referenciado o ID do botão Alternar.

```js
$("#alternar").click(function() {
  if ($(".ms-acal-item").hasClass('black')) {
    $(".ms-acal-item").removeClass('black');
    $(".ms-acal-item").addClass('silver');
  } else {
    $(".ms-acal-item").removeClass('silver');
    $(".ms-acal-item").addClass('black');
  }
});
```

```css
.black {
  background-color: #383838;
}

.silver {
  background-color: #C8C8C8;
}

.ms-acal-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='ms-acal-item'>
</div>

<button id='alternar'>
  Alternar Classe
</button>
```